# How to fix "NameError: no function 'libvlc_new' when running vlc.Instance() on replit

Tags: python, vlc, replit

When trying to create a vlc.Instance()

```
    Instance = vlc.Instance()
```

I get the following error (in my replit console)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
          Instance = vlc.Instance()
       File "/home/runner/personal-assistant/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 1814, in __new__
          return libvlc_new(len(args), args)
       File "/home/runner/personal-assistant/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 4978, in libvlc_new
          _Cfunction('libvlc_new', ((1,), (1,),), class_result(Instance),
       File "/home/runner/personal-assistant/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 302, in _Cfunction
          raise NameError('no function %r' % (name,))
    NameError: no function 'libvlc_new'
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening and how I can fix this problem? I've looked all over online for answers but I can't find any that work (for replit).

Comment: Have you installed vlc in the replit?

Comment: yes -- ive already tried "pip install python-vlc"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (outside of replit) and maybe my solution works for you.

The error might occur for 2 reasons:

#1 vlc is not installed on your system.

- python-vlc is just an interface

#2 vlc is installed (via Snap store), but for some reason doesn't work.

- uninstall vlc and and proceed with the rest:

Install vlc (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt update 

sudo apt install vlc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this doesnt work -- I have contacted replit support on the issue and they are working on it -- please check to make sure your solutions work before posting them!

Comment: I had the same problem, outside of replit, and the solution I presented worked for me. But apparently that did not translate to replit. I apologize for not stating that.